# Updating a data object that gets passed around Vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue, and have inherited a codebase that I need to modify. There's a file called data.js, with a few objects that contain information on cities, like:

```
export default {
  nyc:
    cleaning: 3,
    maintenanceS: 1
  }
}
```

In one component, index.vue, data is imported like any other JS object:

```
import data from '../components/logic/data'
```

In another component, its imported as a prop:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {}
},
props: ['data'],
computed: {
...
```

I've been reading the Vue guide, and I have a loose grasp on how props are passed down from a parent component. Am I correct that index.vue would be the parent component of any other component that takes in 'data' as a prop?

I need to let the user modify 'data' values via a text box:

```
<td>Cleaning: <input type="number"  v-model.number.lazy="cleaning"/></td>
```

Am I correct that v-model is the right way to update these values such that the new values is used across all components? I'm guessing that I also need to write some Javascript in the component to do the updating, but I'm not sure how to go about this. How do I update this value so its used across all components that use the 'data' object?

Thanks!

Comment: could you provide the whole code of index.vue and child components?

Comment: Here's index.vue: https://pastebin.com/28wg3C4A And here's the child component I referenced: https://pastebin.com/GL0Db4aQ Thank you!

Comment: your question it's not clear, could you give concret use ?

Comment: So I need to change a value in the data object, like data.cleaning in my post, through an input field. And I need this new value to be used across all components. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes you can update the value in parent component and it will be changed in child ones automatically

Comment: So something like this? <td>Cleaning: <input type="number"  v-model.number.lazy="data.cleaning"/></td> Or do I need to do an additional javascript function to do that?

Comment: no need to add other js code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181243/discussion-between-boussadjra-brahim-and-no-parachute44).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if a parent component has multiple child ones, it can pass data to them using `props` and any change in the parent component of that data affects automatically the passed data, let's suppose we have a parent component which contains two numbers and there's two child components, one calculates the sum and another one for multiplying them :

```js
Vue.component('sum', { 
props:["n1","n2"],
template:'<div>Sum => <h3>{{n1+n2}}</h3></div>'

})

Vue.component('mult', { 
props:["n1","n2"],
template:'<div>Mult => <h3>{{n1*n2}}</h3></div>'

})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
data:{
      num1:0,
      num2:0       
     } 
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
     <input type="number" v-model.number.lazy="num1" class="form-control">
      <input type="number" v-model.number.lazy="num2" class="form-control">
     <span>Parent => ({{num1}},{{num2}})</span>
     <sum :n1="num1" :n2="num2"></sum>
    <mult :n1="num1" :n2="num2"></mult>
</div>
```

it's a very basic example but it shows the use and the utility of that hierarchy, and the `v-model` directive is very useful when we work with forms and inputs